# Charting Variable number of lines in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataframe with a time column and several serial number columns. I am trying to plot the serial number columns vs time. I am unsure of how to do this being as there are a variable number of serial numbers that could be in the dataframe.

```
  400602902  Time 400621787 400621434 400619512
0     11066   0.1     10518     10948     10795
1     13716   0.2     13206     13688     13420
2     15995   0.3     15194     16367     16091
3     19109   0.4     17485     19128     18949
4     20298   0.5     19811     20296     20298
```

My internet research has brought me to the below code but I am struggling with how to plot multiple lines when i do not know exactly how many there will be.

```
    graphingWindow = tk.Tk()
    graphingWindow.title('Filmcool Siganture Charts')
    graphingWindow.minsize(width=600,height=800)

    #Depth Plot
    figure1 = plt.Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=100)
    ax1 = figure1.add_subplot(111)
    line1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure1, graphingWindow)
    line1.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH)
    depthDF.plot(kind='line', legend=True, ax=ax1, color='r',marker='o', fontsize=10)
    ax1.set_title('EDM Depth Vs. Time')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using some of your data, here's a way to chart each column against `Time` using `matplotlib`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"Time":[0.1,0.2,0.3],"400602902":[11066, 13716, 15995],"400621787":[10518, 13206, 15194]})
x = df.drop("Time", axis=1)

for col in x:
    plt.plot( 'Time', col, data=df, marker='o', markerfacecolor='blue', markersize=12, color='skyblue', linewidth=4)
plt.legend()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: that works great! now how do I get that plot into a tkinter widget?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm unfamiliar with tkinter, but seeing some similarities in your code, I would try this: after the line `ax1 = figure1.add_subplot(111)`, I would insert the for loop and do `ax1.plot( 'Time', col, data=df)`. Then, after `line1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure1, graphingWindow)`, you should be able to call `line1.show()`. Not 100% sure though.